# Reduce Or Remove Vertical Padding Of MDL Textfields

Tags: html, css, material-design, material-design-lite

I have a table that contains an MDL textfield.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Name
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
                <input class="mdl-textfield__input" id="name" type="text">
                <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="name">Name</label>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Name
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
                <input class="mdl-textfield__input" id="age" type="text">
                <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="age">Age</label>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

However, this produces a very ugly result, because the textfields (and therefore the table cells) have a big vertical padding. The cell is 69px high, even though the textfield itself is 29px high.

I have tried to remove the padding of the textfield via css, but that has completely destroyed its geometry. Removing the padding from the table row or altering its size does not change anything.

Is there a way to remove or significantly reduce the vertical padding of the cell or table without damaging the textfield?

**EDIT:**

I have created a pen showing my problem. The padding is light blue, while the actual input element is colored purple:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BWRvrz?editors=1100

Comment: It would be best if you created a [mcve] of your problem, linking all required libraries (use the snippet tool - `<>` button). It is required in order to inspect the problem and provide an appropriate answer. By not providing it, you are drastically reducing your chances of getting an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have achieved what I wanted by using the following style:

```
mdl-textfield{
    padding: 0
}
```

removes the padding.

```
mdl-textfield__label {
    top: 4px
}
```

sets the label to the correct position.

```
mdl-textfield__label:after {
    bottom: 0
}
```

Moves the animation to the correct position.

Answer (score 1):

A less computationally expensive solution that may be considered a hack is to use a negative margin equal to the padding.

```
.mdl-textfield {
    margin: -20px 0;
}
```

Here only one rule is overridden.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way to do it than setting `padding` to `0px` and fixing the label position and animation.

You can set the `.mdl-textfield` margin negative

```
.mdl-textfield {
  margin: -20px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.mdl-textfield {
  margin: (any number);
}
```

That is not a good way to solve this issue, becouse if you look into the function between "mdl-textfield" and "mdl-textfield__input" . the  "mdl-textfield__input" is on the top in the begging, when user fouse the input field,  "mdl-textfield" will be on the top, that is how thay work, so if you just change the margin, the text of placeholder will be blocked. these two div,"mdl-textfield" and "mdl-textfield__input", could be swithed by the javascript itself, so it means you change the margin, you broke the rules of MDL.